# Open Zoom Client app from Firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, zoom-meeting

I have the latest version of the Zoom Client app [directly downloaded from their website](https://zoom.us/download) and installed on Ubuntu 18.04. The Zoom app works fine when I have a meeting number and password.

When I only have a link (eg *something.zoom.us/w/12345?tk=zxcv*), Firefox does not open the Zoom app. But if I use the same link on Google Chrome, it opens the Zoom app correctly.

How do I enable Firefox to open the Zoom app with the correct details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens if zoom desktop client is not running. Make sure zoom client is running and zoom applet is being shown. Then, clicking on the link should give you the following window
[image]

Click on remember my choice

Comment: Thanks, having zoom running worked.

Comment: **Note for Ubuntu 22.04** This answer does not work. [See this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410174/how-to-open-zoom-meeting-link-in-firefox) for a workaround.